# How to run multiple linux commands in python script where order matters

Tags: python, linux, scripting

I'm trying to execute several linux commands sequentially in my python script using subprocess.Popen().  However, it seems like the way I'm writing the script, python is doing some sort of execute and forget and not waiting for step 1 to finish before starting step 2.

Case in point, I'm trying to:

1. Execute a SQL command, which writes the results to a file in /tmp on
   the remote server.
2. After I'm finished using the file, I want to delete the remote file, so we don't run out of space.

What's happening is python seems to run the cmd for step 1 and without waiting for step 1 to complete, it runs step 2.  So the file is still hanging around since the delete is run before the file is created.

Here's my code snippet.  Hopefully someone can tell me how to make it so step 2 only runs after step 1 has completed.  I tried to anonymize/simplify the snippet so pls excuse any mistakes made while anonymizing the code.

```
   sqlCmd = "ssh " + HOST + "mysql -h host -ppwd -q select blah from table where foo = 'bar' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/blah_bydate.csv"
   rmCmd = "ssh " + HOST + " rm -f /tmp/blah_bydate.csv"
   proc = subprocess.Popen(sqlCmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   proc = subprocess.Popen(rmCmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I found something on SO where the suggested solution was to do something like

```
subprocess.Popen([cmd1; cmd2; cmd3], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

which I don't want to do since my commands are parametrized and can be long/complex.

Comment: consider running a single `ssh` session...

Comment: To elaborate on @Karoly: in *nix, if one does `"ls ; cp a.txt b.txt"` the `cp` will not be executed until the `ls` command is finished. And, if you do `"ls && cp a.txt b.txt"` the `cp` will not be executed unless the `ls` has finished successfully. So, build a unified _Cmd_ string that concatenates your `mysql` and `rm` commands with a `;` or `&&` in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) rather than `subprocess.Popen` and it should block until the process has finished.

Comment: Another thing to bear in mind is to make sure you sanitise `HOST`, since you use `shell=True`. There's a warning in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

Comment: thanks for the warning.  i've read the warnings but if shell=False, the command didn't work and gave another error so I have to make shell=True to make everyone (me and python) happy  =)

Comment: Sure. The key thing is just to make sure you don't let unscrupulous internet people give you values of HOST. :P

Comment: @Classified You can probably make that work if you group things as shell parameters into a list and use that.  I'm guessing yours would be something like: sqlCmd = [ "ssh", HOST, "mysql", "-h", "-p", "pwd", "-q", "select blah from table where foo = 'bar' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/blah_bydate.csv'" ]

Answer (score 2):

You can use proc.wait(), which can even take a timeout value, should you need one.